# Ubuntu 16.04 Flickering problem with the external monitor using original tested Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

Recently I got a monitor to use it as an external for my laptop. My bought my laptop about 4 years ago. Its specification are Intel i5 3210m 2,5Ghz with integrated gpu, 12gb ram and Nvidia 610m for external gpu. I connect my external monitor via VGA, because it is a little bit old. I also managed to install properly the original and tested Nvidia 367 driver. Furthermore, I choose from the Nvidia-setting to use the Nvidia gpu as the prefered one.

The problem I have is that when I connect the external monitor to the laptop, the external monitor has a flickering problem. I searched almost all over the internet and I didn't find anything that suits me.

In my opinion, and from what I found, the problem may exists because the intel and nvidia gpu drivers are used in the same time.

```
lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'

Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

So, is there anyone else who has the same or similar problem and find any solution or have any idea what else may be the reason?

Comment: Try installing `ccsm` package and then run it and go to the "Composite" plugin. Try checking "Force independent output repaint"

Comment: Hello, I just tried and unfortunately it didn't work! Any other suggestion?